# How to prevent Windows 7 creating desktop icons vertically

Tags: windows, icons, desktop

I want Windows to only place new icons on the bottom left corner instead of interfering with my neatly organized spaces on the top left of the desktop.
Additionally, I want it to place each new icon on the right of the existing icons (i.e. horizontally).
Hi how can I do this to prevent Windows 7 & 10 from placing new desktop icons directly beneath the last icon (i.e. vertically)?

Comment: You cannot as far as I know.

Comment: Cannot do even PART of the above?